# jquery fields' form emptyness check

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

i'm building a function who will check if some fields of a form are empty. Then, i use this function to submit the form only if there is no empty field.

My function to test emptyness of fields:

```
    function formCompleted(form){
      form.filter(':input').each( function(){
        if( $(this).val() === "" ){
          return false;
        };
      });
    };
```

The function to submit form:

```
    $('#form-id').change(function(){
      if(formCompleted($('#form-id > *'))){
        alert("Form haven't empty fields");
      }else{
        alert('Form have empty fields');
      }
    });
```

**The problem**

The formCompleted function seems to be always false, even when all fields are filled. The form contain input (type="number") and a select (with 3 option).

Any clues?

Comment: you dont have a `return true;` statement in your function..

Answer (score 1):

Use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/), and return true if the empty fields count is 0, mean there is not empty field.

```
function formCompleted(form){
    return form.filter(':input[value=""]').length == 0;
};
```

Comment: Looks great, but when i change a fields value, the value="" attribute in html tag is not update. So all fields looks always empty for javascript.

Comment: Its weird can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function formCompleted(form){
  form.filter(':input').each( function(){
    if( $(this).val() === "" ){
      return false;
    };
  });
  form.filter('select').each( function(){
    if( $(this).val() === "" ){
      return false;
    };
  });
};

$('#form-id').change(function(){
  if(formCompleted($('#form-id'))){ // <----pass the form only
    alert('Form haven't empty fields');
  }else{
    alert('Form have empty fields');
  }
});
```

Comment: you don't need two loops when using `:input`. see http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to return true from `formCompleted()`, so it will return either false or nothing (undefined).

So add a `return true;` statement after your loop, so it returns true if no elements where empty.

```
function formCompleted(form){
    form.filter(':input').each( function(){
        if( $(this).val() === "" ){
          return false;
        };
    });
    return true;
};
```